# Utilising old pc with an android device?

Tags: wireless-networking, remote-desktop, android, webserver, freenas

i have an old pc connected to old router running freenas. but i am thinking of installing ubuntu or windows xp on it. my old lcd monitor for that pc is occupied as an extended display for my laptop so i am hoping to control that pc remotely with my grandpa's old android tablet phone. is there anyway i can access that PC without having connecting a screen everytime and configuring remote access. similarly like freenas has a web gui is there a solution to this?.. thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

[Find the version of Android](https://its.uiowa.edu/support/article/2803) on that tablet with:

- From the home screen, press the Settings Button
- Then select the Settings option
- Scroll down and select About Phone
- Scroll down to Android Version
- The small number under the heading is the version # of Android on your tablet.

Then, [search the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20remote%20desktop%20app) for 'android remote desktop app' and eliminate all those which require a version of Android newer than you have.

Then, check this [Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software#Operating_system_support) for those which have a client for your target PC OS, whichever you select, and which use the same protocol the Android app uses.